# Django Model BooleanField, not required, but also not null choice

Tags: python, django, postgresql

It doesn't seem like the Django model.BooleanField has an attribute for required, only for a null choice. However, I only want a "Yes", "No" choices without the null choice, without forcing the user of the form to select one or the other. Right now, in Postgresql, it shows up as False if No is chosen or if it is not selected. Instead, I want it to distinguish between the two...

So far I am using the blank attribute and setting it to True, which makes the field not required, but when Django saves the form with an empty field to Postgresql, it shows up as False, which isn't something I want. Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't null=False be something you could do in your models? you of course would have to set this in your database as well... as far as I knew booleans could be only true or false, i would suggest to default to one or the other

Comment: But then how do I tell the difference between a user-inputted "False" and just simply leaving it blank?

Comment: Well, you could not set a default value - and if you are using modelforms you can make the drop down custom with choices provided in your model defined by you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should clarify. I am using a BooleanField, but changing it to a RadioSelect on the forms.py file. No matter what I set the default to (it was 'Unspecified'), if the user does not choose the Yes or No button, it will automatically default to the No button, making it impossible to tell what occurred.

Comment: You need to break down the check inside the form, use clean_yourfield for further checking and logic. Or create a validator and assign it to the field.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a choice CharField and from there filter based on the choice selected.